# The relation $x \sim g x g$ in groups

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

While thinking about item (2) in [Standard or good names for relations between maps](https://mathoverflow.net/q/437261), I thought I'd look at the relation $x \sim g x g$ in groups.

Going through all small groups of order at most 64, it seems to me, that for any finite group the connected components all have the same size, and that the number of connected components is a power of 2.  Is this obvious, or false?

NB: What I am really after is a name for the relation.

(edited to reflect YCor's observation)

(edited to reflect LSpice's observation)

Comment: It's not an equivalence relation. For instance, in the free group on $x,y,z$, we have $yxy\simeq x\simeq zxz$ but $yxy\sim zxz$ fails.

Comment: Or more explicitly, in the symmetric group on $\ge 4$ elements, if $\tau_{a,b}$ is the transposition swapping $a,b$, then $\tau_{0,1}\sim\tau_{1,2}\sim\tau_{2,3}$ but $\tau_{0,1}\sim\tau_{2,3}$ fails.

Comment: Actually, for $\mathfrak 4$ it seems still to be an equivalence relation.  For your example, I have $(1,3)(2,4)(1,2)(1,3)(2,4) = (3,4)$.  The smallest group I could find where it fails has order 12, and has Gap structure description $C_3 : C_4$, with three generators, where $f_1 f_2 f_1 = 1$, $f_3^2 1 f_3^2 = f_3$, but $f_2$ and $f_3$ are unrelated.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I messed up something.

Comment: OK: all transpositions are related by $\sim$. But in the symmetric group $S_n$, if I'm correct, when $n=2\bmod(4)$, an $n$-cycle $c$ is related to a transposition $\tau_{i,j}$ iff the number $k$ such that $c^k(i)=j$ (which is unique mod 2) is odd. Hence $\tau_{0,2}\sim\tau_{0,1}\sim (012345)$ but $\tau_{0,2}\nsim (012345)$ (this yields an example in $S_6$; I haven't checked $S_4,S_5$ and anyway your example of order 12 is smaller).

Comment: I checked $S_4$ and $S_5$ with a computer.

Comment: @LSpice: $x \sim y \iff \exists g: x = gyg$ is the original, and the one YCor looked at is the transitive closure of this relation

Comment: I should have added: ... if there is a $g\in G$, sorry.

Comment: What I am interested in is precisely what @VilleSalo writes, and, even more precisely, a catchy name for this relation.

Comment: A curiosity: if $G$ has odd order (so this graph is connected), is it true that $x\sim y$ for all $x,y$? You might check for small $|G|$. I'm just curious whether this is qualitatively different from the relation $\sim'$ defined as $x\sim' xg^2$.

Comment: Yes, it seems so.  I tested all small groups of order at most 127.

Comment: In fact, it seems that it is an equivalence relation if the order is not a multiple of 4, or at most 11.

Comment: @MartinRubey When you said "it seems so", did you mean just the first question of YCor (whether it is universal when the group has odd order)? Did you also check whether it is the same relation as $\sim'$?

Comment: @verret Isn't that equivalent? For groups of odd order, $\sim'$ is obviously universal.

Comment: In case you meant for arbitrary finite groups rather than odd order, $\sim$ and $\sim'$ certainly do not coincide in general. In particular, ${\sim}\subseteq{\sim'}$ only if $\sim'$ is transitive, i.e., if squares form a subgroup: indeed, $g^{-1}\sim ghg^{-1}gh=g^{-1}g^2h^2$, thus ${\sim}\subseteq{\sim'}$ implies that $g^2h^2$ is a square.

Comment: I have now checked small groups again, up to order 40.  Apparently: if the order is not a multiple of 4 or at most 11, then both relations coincide and are equivalence relations.  Otherwise, the following cases occur: they coincide and are equivalence relations, they coincide and are not equivalence relations (only in order 16 and 32 so far), they differ, and neither is an equivalence relation.  Among these small groups there is none where one relation is an equivalence and the other is not.

Comment: @MartinRubey Are you sure? This directly contradicts my previous comment, where I proved that whenever the two relations coincide, they are equivalence relations.

Comment: Let $G$ be the group `SmallGroup(16, 4)` https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Nontrivial_semidirect_product_of_Z4_and_Z4 of order 16 with 4 generators $f_1,\dots,f_4$.  Then, apparently, $f_1 f_1 = f_4$, $f_2 f_4 f_2 = f_3 f_4$, but $1\not\sim f_3 f_4$.  For the other relation, we have $f_1^2 = f_4$, $f_4 f_2^2 = f_3 f_4$ and $1\not\sim f_3 f_4$.  Morever, my (possibly buggy) program says that the relations are the same.

Comment: Since you claim $1\nsim'f_3f_4$, i.e., $f_3f_4$ is not a square, we also have $f_1^{-1}\nsim'f_1^{-1}f_3f_4=f_1f_2^2$, but $f_1^{-1}\sim(f_1f_2)f_1^{-1}(f_1f_2)=f_1f_2^2$. Thus either the relations are not the same, or some of the claims in your comment are wrong.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, sorry.  The relations are not the same, they are only isomorphic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's indeed quite immediate.

Indeed, let $\simeq$ be the equivalence relation generated by this relation. Then $x\simeq y$ iff the images of $x$ and $y$ in $G/G^2$ are equal. Here $G^2$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by squares, so $G/G^2$ is the largest 2-elementary abelian quotient of $G$. ($G$ is not assumed finite.)

To prove the claim, one direction is clear ($x\simeq y$ implies $xG^2=yG^2$). For the converse, first observe that
$$x\simeq gxg\simeq hgxgh\simeq (hg)^{-1}hgxgh(hg)^{-1}=xghg^{-1}h^{-1},$$
and by induction it follows that $x\simeq xz$ for every $z\in [G,G]$. Then
$$xg^2=gxg\; g^{-1}(x^{-1}g^{-1}xg)g\simeq gxg\simeq x.$$
So by induction $xz\simeq x$ for every $z\in G^2$.

(For a name: it's the equivalence relation induced by equality modulo a normal subgroup, or equivalently, fibers of a group homomorphism, so this is the most standard kind of equivalence relations in group theory.)

Comment: Does this also prove that the number of components is a power of 2?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: The name for the relation (not the induced equivalence relation) will appear in a computer program, in the form of a method `set_your_name_goes_here(x, y)`, which then requires that an unknown map $s$ satisfies $x = s y s$, for two given maps $x$ and $y$.  In the most trivial case, one can thus require that $s$ is an involution. So, maybe you can suggest an answer for the linked question in this sense!

Comment: When you say "it's quite immediate" in your first sentence, is "it" the fact mentioned by @MartinRubey [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437797/the-relation-x-sim-g-y-g-in-groups#comment1128688_437805) (and in the question) that there are $2$-power many components?

Comment: @LSpice I mean the whole thing: that the components are fibers of the "2-elementary-abelianization" (which implies in turn, for a finite group, that all components have the same cardinal and that the number of components is a power of 2).

Answer (score 5):

EDIT (11/01/2023) : I've expanded this answer to show that, if $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ of odd order such that $G/N$ is an elementary abelian $2$-group, then the relation is universal on each coset of $N$.

(In particular, this covers the cases when $G$ has  odd or twice odd order, which were mentioned in the comments.)

Lemma: If $a$ and $b$ have odd order, then $aba=b$ implies $a=1$.

Proof: $aba=b$ implies $b$ inverts $a$ by conjugation. This means $b^2$ commutes with $a$ but since $b$ has odd order, $b$ commutes with $a$ so the original equation simplifies to $a^2=1$ which implies $a=1$ since $a$ has odd order.

Now, let $x\in G$ and let $\sigma_x:Nx\to Nx$ be given by $g\mapsto gxg$.

We show that $\sigma_x$ is injective. Let $g,h\in Nx$ such that $\sigma_x(g)=\sigma_x(h)$, that is $hxh=gxg=hh^{-1}gxhh^{-1}g$ which implies $xh=h^{-1}gxhh^{-1}g$. Writing $a=h^{-1}g$ and $b=xh$, this becomes $b=aba$. Since $G/N$ is an elementary abelian $2$-group and $x,g,h\in Nx$, it follows that $a,b\in N$ and the Lemma implies that $a=1$, that is $g=h$, as required.

By finiteness, $\sigma_x$ is also surjective and it follows that the relation is universal on $Nx$.